# link inside a p tag making an error

Tags: html, css, href, paragraph, article

I have an issue whenever i try to make a link inside my paragraph in HTML. I want to make a link to a different html site when you click on "her" in the text, and i get an error, that i don't know how to fix.

```
  <p> Hvem er Kristoffer Tølbøll? Det er et spørgsmål jeg hører meget sjælendt, men til jer, der ikke ved det endnu
   er Kristoffer Tølbøll, den næste store profil inden for det danske erhvervsliv, samt den reinkarnerede Cassanova på en gang.
   Lyder der for godt til at være sandt? Det er det bestemt ikke. Jeg har mange kvaliteter og kompetancer, som jeg dagligt gør brug af på mit studie som datamatiker,
   samtidig er jeg filosof, filantrop og komiker. Vil du også gerne være alle disse ting? Tilmeld dig med dit fornavn og efternavn så tager jeg kontakt til dig.
   (Gælder kun lækre piger i alderen 18-25 læs alle vores krav <a href src="terms.html" her </a>
 </p>
```

what can i do?

Comment: If you're linking to a different website then you will need an absolute URL. Also, close the starting `<a>` tag and use `href` not `src`. Something like, `<a href="http://example.com/terms.html">her</a>`.

Comment: You forgot to close the anchor tag ..See `<a href src="terms.html"`. Replace it with `<a href="terms.html">`

Comment: <a href="absoluteurl"> her </a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the a tag wrong. You need to close the tag, and href is the attribute you want to set:

```
<a href="terms.html">her</a>
```

If linking to an external site, you will also need the full base URL.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the anchor tag properly.

Also, it is the `href` attribute that has to be used in place of `src` attribute. `href` attribute specifies the URL of the page the link goes to.

Thus, replace

```
<a href src="terms.html" her </a>
```

with

```
<a href="terms.html"> her </a>
```